# AWS Lambda request timestamp format changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda event request timestamp format changed while testing it from Alexa skill.

**this.event.request.timestamp**

Earlier it was "2017-07-15T14:38:48Z" and now it is "1500139534627" while testing it from Alexa Skill.

Even it is showing proper timestamp "2017-07-15T14:38:48Z" when tested from Amazon ECHO device.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to a [known issue](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/78372/timestamp-is-sent-in-different-formats.html) that Amazon says it is "working on".